# Add integer value to string using parseInt not working on dynamic added content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My HTML looks like this

```
<span class="responsesCount"><b>0<b/></span> 

<div class="addOne">submitResponse</div>
```

I'm using Jquery to increment the class (responsesCount) by one every time a user post a response to a comment.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate",function(event) {

    $(document).on('click', '.addOne', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var commentCount = ".responsesCount";

        var num = $(commentCount).text();
        var newnum = parseInt(parseFloat(num), 10)+1;
        $(commentCount).text(newnum);       
    });    
});
```

The code works as expected when page first loads incrementing by one.

The problem is when i load dynamic content into the page via ajax i get an unexpected result it seems to concatenate and not increment like expected

```
0
1
12
13
14
15
2
```

the actual output looks like this: `12 13 14 15 2`

```
 <span class="responsesCount"><b>12131415<b/></span>
```

i've also have used the following snippets but none seem to work.

```
$(commentCount).text(parseInt(num) + 1);
$(commentCount).text(parseInt(num, 10) + 1);
$(commentCount).text(num + 1);
$(commentCount).text(num++);
$(commentCount).text(++num);
$(commentCount).text(num * 2);

var num = $(commentCount).text();
$(commentCount).text(parseInt(num) +1);
```

the code i use to load more content into the page.

```
$(document).on('click', '.moreResult', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();    
  var res = $(".feed:last").attr("id");

$.ajax({
  url: "process/loadmore.php?lastid=" + res,
  success: function(html) {     
      if(html) {
           $(".addResults").append(html).trigger('create');    
      } else { 
           $(".moreResult").html("End!");      
      }
    }
  });
 });     
});
```

I've been pulling my hair all night with this issue nothing seems to work! any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you all for help in advance.

Comment: That float, int line is wrong. Pick one, not both.

Comment: What are you loading with the Ajax call exactly? More responsesCount elements?

Comment: @Benjamin Your custom event is "pagecreate" and you're triggering "create". What does `html` contain in your ajax success?

Comment: @epascarello I'm loading more comments into page

Comment: @LShetty i am using jquery mobile that's why i need "pagecreate" and i need "create" on the return html because i'm using custom jquery mobile attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you doing so complicated ? Do you really have to parse ? If no, look at this demo :

### **Code used :**

```
$(document).on("create",function(event) { // Your event is called create, isn't it ?
    var count = 0;

    $(".addOne").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".responsesCount").text(++count);       
    });    
});
```

```js
$(function(event) {
    var count = 0;

    $(".addOne").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".responsesCount").text(++count);       
    });    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="responsesCount"><b>0<b/></span> 

<div class="addOne">submitResponse</div>
```

### **If yes, then look at that one :**

```
$(document).on("create",function(event) { // Your event is called create, isn't it ?

    $('.addOne').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var num = $(commentCount).text();
        var newnum = parseInt(num, 10) + 1;
        $(".responsesCount").text(newnum);       
    });    
});
```

In the above code, I cleaned everything to focus on the most important. You should not do `parseInt(parseFloat(...))` because `parseInt` is waiting for a `string` and `parseFloat` returns a `float`.

```js
$(function() {

    $('.addOne').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var num = $(".responsesCount").text();
        var newnum = parseInt(num, 10) + 1;
        $(".responsesCount").text(newnum);       
    });    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="responsesCount"><b>0</b></span>

<div class="addOne">submitResponse</div>
```

Comment: `$(function(event) {` should have been `jQuery(function($) {`. Because first argument in the callback is a reference to jQuery

Comment: @Ninetainedo the problem is when i click on the loadmore button and load new content into the page. when i click on the "addOne" div after new content has been added i get 12131415 instead of it iterating normally..

Comment: @Ninetainedo i will try your corrections later on tonight when i get home.....thanks for your help

Comment: @Ninetainedo it worked! thank you! Your solution help me out a lot THUMBS UP!